# How to create a CSS loader with gradient border and transparency?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to do a loader with HTML and CSS I have the loader done but there's an issue when I have information behind the center of the loader the information doesn't show and the reason is because I have background: white; that I need to avoid showing the gradient because if I remove the white color and put transparent the gradient appears.

So I need to fix the problem when I have something behind the loader

```css
.loader {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.loader .circle {
  background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #a03297, #e90b5a);
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 1px;
  animation: rot 2s linear infinite; 
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.circle > div {
  background:white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 1px;
}

@keyframes rot {
   0% { transform: rotate(0deg) }
   100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="circle">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>


<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 140px;">aaaaaaasssssssssssssssssçççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççssssssss</p>
```

Comment: Please show us an example of text hidden and the issue occurring

Comment: Okay is done you have now a text and as you can see part of the text doesn't appear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `mask` to make the inner part transparent:

```css
.loader {
  background:linear-gradient(yellow, #e90b5a);
  /* Show only 10px from the border */
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,#0000 calc(100% - 10px),#fff 0);
          mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,#0000 calc(100% - 10px),#fff 0);
  border-radius: 50%;  
  position: fixed;
  inset : calc(50% - 50px);
  animation: rot 2s linear infinite; 
}

@keyframes rot {
   100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,grey,white)
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```